# Get data from external JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm obtaining data from an API and its JSON is stored on a separate file.

The URL for this file looks like this:

```
http://events.com/rsvp.php?id=1234
```

The JSON on the above page looks like this:

```
{
  rsvp: true
}
```

The `id` query string differs for each contact, so `id 1234` might have `rsvp: true` but `id 4321` might have `rsvp: false`.

What I'm trying to do is check the URL, get the value of the `rsvp` node and then, perform some action.

At the moment, with my request, I'm seeing the log `error`, unsure why?

```html
<!-- this gets the id field -->
{% set contact_id = request.query_dict.id %}

{% set base_url = "http://events.com/rsvp.php?id=" %}
{% set url = base_url + contact_id %}

<script>

$(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: "{{ url }}",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){
      console.log(result);
    },
    error:function() {
      console.log("Error")
    }
  });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Check the console to see a description of the exact issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is invalid.

Property names in JSON must be strings, not identifiers.

```
{
  "rsvp": true
}
```

Generate your JSON with [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/json_encode), not with whatever method you are currently using.